# "I am tall, and, because of a disease, I am weak." or "I am tall, and because of a disease, I am weak."?

Tags: commas

I know that it can be a stylistic choice to not place commas in between two full sentences separate by a conjunction when those sentences are very short. Ignore this stylistic choice for the example. If it helps, assume the sentences are longer.

Comment: There is also a stylistic rule that some people follow of never putting commas on both sides of a word like *and* or *but*.

Comment: @petershor ah, interesting

Comment: @petershor I think I read that stylistic comma choices in the U.S. have been trending toward non-use

Comment: If you didn't have the parenthetical "because of a disease" phrase in the sentence would you have a comma before the "and"? I'm asking because both "I am tall and I am weak" and "I am tall, and I am weak" are reasonable sentences but if you would not insert the comma in the short version there is no need to insert it in the longer one. Having said that I would use "but" rather than "and" in any case as being weak would normally be surprising in someone who was tall.